# Annotation @Type dosent find attribute type to map classes in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to map 2 classes in hibernate with `@Type` annotation.

I read great amount of publication that say to use `@Type(type = "")`, but when I use it I got next:

[image]
[image]

I tried to use attribute value, with declaring class but it also didn't work:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I needed to import hibernate types 60 instead of hibernate types 52, now it is solved)